# Is there a good dual monitor arm solution for iMac 27" i7s?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, ergonomics

I currently have an iMac 27" and am considering purchasing another to run in [target display mode](https://superuser.com/questions/128962/can-i-use-a-27-imac-as-a-additional-monitor-for-another-27-imac).

My desk space is a little limited. Is there a dual monitor arm solution that can support the weight of two iMac 27" units ([30.5 pounds (13.8 kg)](http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html)) as well as their width ([25.6 inches (65.0 cm)](http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html)) in a side-by-side landscape configuration?

I looked at the [Ergotron LX Dual Side by Side](http://www.ergotron.com/Products/tabid/65/PRDID/354/language/en-US/default.aspx) but the iMacs appear to exceed the width and weight limit this device is rated for.

I'm open to alternate solutions to arms, such as a multi-unit desk stand/mount, but a wall mount is not possible for me at this time.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

There isn't a suitable dual monitor solution that I could find. I ended up purchasing two Innovative iLift 7517-1500's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I spent a lot of time trawling different boards and finally settled on purchasing two [iLife 7517-1500](http://www.thehumansolution.com/ilift-lcd-monitor-arm-imac-g5-apple-cinema-display.html)'s from Innovative.

I have both iMac's on them now, and they are working fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, at least at ergotron, you'll have to use two arms, one for each of your iMacs, as indicate their ["quick find"](http://www.ergotron.com/Support/QuickFinderbyDisplayModel/tabid/387/ManufacturerID/949/ModelID/23930/CategotyID/5/Default.aspx) page.